# C++: any way to avoid repeating a base class template argument twice?

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

Say I have a templated base class

```
template <typename T>
class Base;
```

and a derived class for which the above template argument is verbose to type out:

```
class Derived : Base<SomeVerboseType>;
```

Is there any way one can do something like:

```
class Derived : Base<T>
{
  using T = SomeVerboseType;
};
```

The above doesn't work because T is not declared before it is used. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Move your using statement up 3 lines.

Comment: I think usually what you do is theres a using in the base class (like `using Foo = T;`), and then the derived can just do `using Foo = Base::Foo;` (or just refer to `Base::Foo` when you need it)

Comment: Moving the `using` statement 4 lines up would look even better.

Comment: What if `Derived` is also templated say on `V`, and the `T` to use for `Base<T>` is deduced from `V` and the way it is deduced is verbose?

Comment: *The above doesn't work because T is not declared before it is used. Is there any way around this?*  Yes there is a way around this: declare T before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, place the typedef in the base class:

```
class SomeVerboseType {

};


template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    using Ty = T;
};

class Derived : public Base<SomeVerboseType> {
    Ty foo;
};
```